# COALESCE and IFNULL does not return 0 when using ISNULL(example,0) in MySQL db

Tags: mysql, sql, coalesce, isnull

I am trying to return 0 instead of nothing when querying my MySQL database, because I have a web page with charts and tables where lots of the important rows don't show up since the query returns null. This is my original SQL statement:

```
SELECT Department, SUM(ExtVal) AS ExtVal, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity
FROM Table1 WHERE Code <> 'AA' AND Code <> 'BB'
GROUP BY Department
ORDER BY Department
```

The above statement only returns data for only 2 of the Departments since the others are null. This is my updated SQL statement:

```
SELECT Department, SUM(COALESCE(ExtVal,0)) AS ExtVal, SUM(COALESCE(Quantity, 0)) AS Quantity
FROM Table1 WHERE Code <> 'AA' AND Code <> 'BB'
GROUP BY Department
ORDER BY Department
```

It only returns data for 2 departments though, even though there are 4. There are no errors when I run my php script from the terminal and I can access the web page which shows this data with no errors. I tried replacing the COALESCE function with ISNULL and it still doesn't work.

Here is some sample data of what is outputted:

[image]

Here is some sample data of what I want to be outputted:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you try `SUM(CASE WHEN ExtVal IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE ExtVal END)` instead of `SUM(COALESCE(ExtVal,0))`?

Comment: Post the sample data from that table.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I added some pictures now

Comment: You still need to post some sample ***input*** data.

Comment: @sstan The information is straight from the MySQL database and is confidential, I can't post it.

Comment: I provided an answer anyways, because I think it makes sense based on the information you provided.  But there really is nothing preventing you from posting some sample input and output data.  If you're dealing with confidential data, then just recreate the problem with test tables and data, and post that instead.  We shouldn't be expected to guess the missing information.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
SELECT Department, 
   COALESCE(SUM(ExtVal),0) AS ExtVal, 
   COALESCE(SUM(Quantity), 0) AS Quantity
FROM Table1 WHERE Code <> 'AA' AND Code <> 'BB'
GROUP BY Department
ORDER BY Department
```

I guess that is even better perfomance

Comment: Still didn't work. I think I need to have a COALESCE for Department too, since that will be null as well. But when I do COALESCE (Department, Department) AS Department it does the same thing.

Comment: provide sqlfiddle please

Comment: `COALESCE` returns the first non-null element from the list. @Michael

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your filter `WHERE Code <> 'AA' AND Code <> 'BB'` is completely excluding certain departments that never show up in your results.

If you want to ensure that you get a row for *every* department, then instead of filtering on `Code`, you can instead use aggregation conditionally based on the `Code` field:

```
select department,
       coalesce(sum(case when code <> 'AA' and code <> 'BB' then ExtVal end), 0) as ExtVal,
       coalesce(sum(case when code <> 'AA' and code <> 'BB' then Quantity end), 0) as Quantity
  from Table1
 group by Department
 order by Department
```